# Using an enumerator still causes mulitple hits to the database

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
        var schedEvents = _dataContext.ScheduledEvents.Where(se => eventParents.Contains(se.HierarchyItem.Id));
        var schedEventsEnum = schedEvents.GetEnumerator();
        while (schedEventsEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            string eventID = schedEventsEnum.Current.Id.ToString();
            string eventName = schedEventsEnum.Current.EventName.ToString();

            jsonStr += "{ \"id\" : \"" + eventID + "\", \"text\" : \"" + eventName + "\"},";
        }
```

eventParents is built up before this, but it's just a list of hierarchical item IDs used for the comparison (the aim is to find all events that are children of an ID in that list).  That part seems to work fine.  The first line of the code hits the database once and pulls everything I want.  However, once it gets to the GetEnumerator part it starts hitting the database again which is what I'm trying to avoid.  But I'm not sure why this might be happening.

I'm doing basically the same thing earlier in the code to go through the Hierarchical items and it just hits the db once so I'm not sure why getting the enumerator for this one might be different.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just doing `foreach (var item in schedEvents)`?

Comment: How are you determining that it is hitting the DB on that first line?  And why are you not using Linq or a foreach to create your JSON?  At the very least you should be using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I wasn't even looking at that, but yes, also, please don't build JSON using string manipulation - that's just begging for issues with special characters. You can easily build JSON like this by creating and serializing a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, or even a `List<object>` containing anonymous types.

Comment: If you are looking at this in your debugger and after the first line you inspect `schedEvents` the debugger will enumerate the result thus causing a call to your DB.  Then the following code would cause another.  Is that how you are determining that it is hitting the DB twice?

Comment: I wasn't using a foreach because when I had first done the other portion for the hierarchy data it seemed like it was hitting the DB on every loop, now I'm thinking I may have been mistaken.  I just tried to use foreach for this and I'm still hitting the DB the same amount of times as I was.  But the multiple hits seem to be going to a view with a count of people in each event. And to answer how I know I'm hitting the DB on the first line I'm using NHibernateProfiler and walk through the lines.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the profiler (http://i.imgur.com/9CD4cpm.png). The highlighted query with 59 results is from the first line, of the code above, it's the query with the WHERE IN.  The rest of those occur later and they are just hitting the view I mentioned for each event from that first query.